# Why do du's subdirectory values not sum up to total?

Tags: linux, command-line, disk-usage

I'm trying to use `du` to investigate disk usage in a directory like so:

```
du -hd1 | sort -rh
```

This gives me a list that starts as follows

```
61G     .
7.9G    ./A
5.1G    ./B
2.7G    ./.C
1.6G    ./.D
1.2G    ./.E
1.2G    ./F
850M    ./.G
724M    ./H
666M    ./I
281M    ./J
249M    ./.K
150M    ./.L
```

The rest of the list sums up to less than 1GB and there are no large files directly contained in that directory:

```
ls -Slh
total 1.8M
...
```

What is the source of the discrepancy between the total 61GB and the sum of less than 25GB of the directory sums?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The calls above miss large hidden files.  Here is the result with `du -a`

```
du -ahd1 .  | sort -rh | head
61G     .
38G     ./.xsession-errors
7.9G    ./A
5.1G    ./B
...
```

Comment: Also `ls -Slh` doesn't count hidden files in "total" (add `-a`) and counts all hard links to a same files so can't be used for disk usage.

Comment: Large .xsession-errors files seem to be a fun topic in their own...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `du` calculates **the whole** subtree usage, and option `-d1` only **prints** data up to the first hierarchie level. Your `ls` calculates only the first level.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. I should use `du -ahd1 | sort -rh` to include files, or use -a on the ls.

Answer (score -1):

if you just want one total;

```
# du -ms
```